# How to find Maclaurin series of $y={(1+x)}^{1/x}$ at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> How to find Maclaurin series of $y={(1+x)}^{1/x}$ at $x=0$ ?

I can't find it when it comes to $f'(0), f''(0)$. I have used limit, but somehow I don't know what to do with the $\frac{1}{x}$ term.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be expanding this around $x = 0$?

Comment: Note that $$z=\frac1x\ln(1+x)-1=\frac1x\left(x-\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3+o(x^3)\right)-1=-\frac12x+\frac13x^2+o(x^2)$$ hence $$e^z=1+z+\frac12z^2+o(z^2)=1-\frac12x+\frac13x^2+\frac12\left(-\frac12x\right)^2+o(x^2)$$ that is $$y=(1+x)^{1/x}=e\cdot e^z=e-\frac{e}2x+\frac{11e}{24}x^2+o(x^2)$$

Comment: @amcerbu Why not?

Comment: @Did: why post your answer as a comment?